# Sharing data between apps with same library

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Is there anyway I can do something like this

1. all data I/O functions are written in a library package
2. data can only be shared between apps with this library (optional)
3. every apps with this library can initiate the "DB" at first time, and later-installed apps can access the same "DB"

I thought ContentProvider is a perfect solution for me, but it seems that condition 3 is impossible.

any suggestion plz?

Comment: Because the ContentProvider is brought by one app, not all of them. And if it is brought by all of them, who can you decide, which one to use.

Comment: @flx He phrased the question explicitly saying that 1) data I/O is performed in a library package; and 2) data can only be shared between apps with this library. Therefore, as far as I can see, he is already conceding that the user must have said library package installed before using any of the "client" apps.

Comment: You can probably make a services that controls the Database, and require it to be installed for each dependent app. Then use that service to store data. Just a thought. Don't know the implementation details of this, but from Object Oriented point of view, it is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all data I/O functions are written in a library package

OK.

> data can only be shared between apps with this library (optional)

Perfectly fine with the proper permissions for your provider ([signature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)).

> every apps with this library can initiate the "DB" at first time, and later-installed apps can access the same "DB"
>
> I thought ContentProvider is a perfect solution for me, but it seems that condition 3 is impossible.

It's up to you to code the underlying structure of your data. Since you already assumed that the provider will belong in a dedicated library package, a possible solution is:

1. Implement your provider in package `com.mysuite.library`.
2. Publish this app in the Play Store.
3. Make client apps A, B and C.
4. Publish them in the Play Store.
5. Require your users to download this library package whenever apps A, B or C can't find `com.mysuite.library` installed.

However, if you don't want to provide a central package, I believe you will need to serve a provider in each of your own apps, with different authorities (to avoid CONFLICTING_PROVIDER error). Upon initializing each client, you first check if there is another provider in your namespace (com.mysuite.provider*), assuming you either know all possible authorities you are going to create and/or iterate among them when searching (com.mysuite.provider1, 2 etc.).

However, this proposition may create problems with custom backups (say, if only one of the clients is backed up), which will force the re-creation of data. It certainly has caveats and is definitely more complex (ugly, IMHO), but it *can* be made to work.

Personally, I'd stick with option 1 (library package). I don't see users complaining when downloading required library packages for apps.

It's just an architectural decision, really.

Answer (score 0):

There are only four ways to maintain shared data:

1. You have a single APK that stores the data and makes it available to other apps.  If this app is uninstalled the data is gone.
2. Every app maintains its own copy of the data but synchronizes changes to the others.
3. The data is stored on the SD card. This is generally a poor solution though several apps do it.
4. The data is stored on a server and is only accessible when the device has a network connection.

Once you've chosen where you want your data to reside, you can transfer it around by any number of mechanisms.

`ContentProvider` is a good choice if you are not storing the data on SD card or on a server, but you want to be able to transfer the data to apps that don't know it exists using `content:` URI's.

If you have no need to ever share any of this data with anyone outside your particular suite of apps, and your data is not structured as a database, you may prefer a simpler transport.